# Highcharts (SVG) text in Times New Roman for phantomjs but everything else in Helvetica

Tags: php, pdf, svg, highcharts, phantomjs

When I use **phantomjs rasterize**, make a PDF of my whole page, and print it normally or view it on Chrome or Firefox the page shows **Helvetica** as the font.

But when **phantomjs** does the PDF, everything is fine except the Highcharts SVG. All the text is in what looks like Times New Roman.

Anyone know why this is, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

SVG is in a different namespace, and HighCharts sets the following as the default:

> Note that since the default font styles are applied in the renderer, it is ignorant of the individual chart options and must be set globally. Defaults to `{font-family:"'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",font-size:"12px"}`.

Use the following CSS to reset it:

```
 .highcharts-root { font-family: inherit; }
```

Or for older versions of HighCharts:

```
 svg { font-family: inherit; }
```

**References**

- [chart.style | Highcharts API Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.style)
- [Style by CSS | Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css)